# How to compile .ccf file using CMI in Sentaurus TCAD?

Tags: synopsys

I have gone through the Compact Model interface manual provided by Synopsys. They only mentioned to compile the .ccf file using cmi compiler and generate .so.arch file. However, there are no more details regarding this. I couldn't find much help from anywhere else. Hence, It would be really helpful if someone could guide me in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helo,
I am showing you here how to generated .so.arch file

first open your terminal window
i am assuming that you have loaded all the synopsys commands needed.
then go to the folder which you have  .C file extension it is a c++ file(lets say filename.C)
then invoke this command in your terminal windows as shown below

```
   cmi -c filename.C
```

then it will generate `filename.o` file in the same folder
then invoke this command as shown below

```
   cmi filename.o
```

then it will generate `filename.so.arch` files arch will be different depending upon your OS architecture for my case it is 64-Bit
so my generated filename will be as `filename.so.linux64`
I hope this will help you to generate what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. :)